# Providing concrete type values for generic method parameters

Tags: c#, generics, parameters

I have a generic interface that defines functionality to secure particular value types. Particular provider implementations are able to protect some value type values (i.e. `ISecurityProvider<int>`) **or** strings (`ISecurityProvider<string>`). That's why I put a generic type constraint to `IConvertible` to cover both.

Provider interface definition

```
public interface ISecurityProvider<TSecurable>
    where TSecurable : IConvertible // to constrain to struct types AND string
{
    TSecurable Secure(TSecurable value);
}
```

Then I have my entity classes that should be able to use these providers and secure their own properties based on security provider's implementation.

I define an abstract base entity class that actual ones inherit from

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    protected bool IsSecured { get; set; }

    protected virtual void SecureSelf<TSecurable>(ISecurityProvider<TSecurable> provider)
        where TSecurable : IConvertible
    {
        if (!this.IsSecured)
        {
            this.IsSecured = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Example entity with identity property that has to be secured.

```
public class SomeDataRecord : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override void SecureSelf<TSecurable>(ISecurityProvider<TSecurable> provider)
    {
        if (!this.IsSecured)
        {
            base.SecureSelf(provider);
            this.Id = provider.Secure(this.Id); // COMPILER ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> *The best overloaded method match for 'ISecurityProvider.Secure(TSecurable)' has some invalid arguments.*

**How should I call `provider.Secure()` method to make it work?**

### Additional information

Basically I would like my individual entity classes to secure all applicable properties which may be of different types. As in my example where I have an integer and a string property.

My `SecureSelf` method should secure all of them at the same time as they're all relying on the same `IsSecured` property. So my example is not really the best one. I should likely rather provide a security provider factory to my `SecureSelf` method and internally it should get particular provider instances to secure indiviual types of properties. Or so I think...

Comment: `this.Id` is `int` but the parameter is of generic type `TSecurable`.

Comment: @DavidG: That's true, but `TSecurable` has `IConvertible` constraint and `System.Int32` does implement it. So it should satisfy `TSecurable` constraints... And casting `(TSecurable)this.Id` doesn't work either...

Comment: Yes, `int` goes up to `IConvertible` but cannot be cast down to `TSecurable`.

Comment: Nope, it only ensures the parameter must implement IConvertible, but your method is generic, so, if your code will compile, if you pass an ISecurityProvider<SomStrangeClass>() TSecurable will not match int. Make the full class generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the way you're trying to use `Secure` you should put the constraint on the method instead of on the interface:

```
public interface ISecurityProvider
{
    TSecurable Secure<TSecurable>(TSecurable value) where TSecurable : IConvertible;
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    protected bool IsSecured { get; set; }

    protected virtual void SecureSelf(ISecurityProvider provider)
    {
        if (!this.IsSecured)
        {
            this.IsSecured = true;
        }
    }
}

public class SomeDataRecord : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected override void SecureSelf(ISecurityProvider provider)
    {
        if (!this.IsSecured)
        {
            base.SecureSelf(provider);
            this.Id = provider.Secure(this.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not even compile: Error 1 SomeDataRecord.SecureSelf<TSecurable>(ISecurityProvider)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Ok so `ISecurityProvider` now becomes some sort of a factory, that can secure various different types... What would be the best way to separate these into their own classes and not implement all security conversions in a single class?

Comment: In other words... An example of `ISecurityProvider` would be helpful even though it would return same values (`Secure(1) => 1`, `Secure("something") => "something"`).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that exception because "int" is not "TSecurable", you can avoid this making BaseEntity generic and in your specific class inherit from the base with a concrete type:

```
public interface ISecurityProvider<TSecurable>
where TSecurable : IConvertible // to constrain to struct types AND string
{
    TSecurable Secure(TSecurable value);
}

public abstract class BaseEntity<TSecurable> where TSecurable : IConvertible
{
    protected bool IsSecured { get; set; }

    protected virtual void SecureSelf(ISecurityProvider<TSecurable> provider)
    {
        if (!this.IsSecured)
        {
            this.IsSecured = true;
        }
    }
}

public class SomeDataRecord : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected override void SecureSelf(ISecurityProvider<int> provider)
    {
        if (!this.IsSecured)
        {
            base.SecureSelf(provider);
            this.Id = provider.Secure(this.Id); // COMPILER ERROR
        }
    }

}
```

Also, if everything will be IConvertible you can use a non-generic approach:

```
public interface ISecurityProvider
{
    IConvertible Secure(IConvertible value);
}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    protected bool IsSecured { get; set; }

    protected virtual void SecureSelf(ISecurityProvider provider)
    {
        if (!this.IsSecured)
        {
            this.IsSecured = true;
        }
    }
}

public class SomeDataRecord : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected override void SecureSelf(ISecurityProvider provider)
    {
        if (!this.IsSecured)
        {
            base.SecureSelf(provider);
            this.Id = (int)provider.Secure(this.Id);
            this.Name = (string)provider.Secure(this.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But that's not what I want. Suppose my example that also has the `Name` property. How would I be able to secure both integers and strings then? I can't inherit `BaseEntity<int>` and `BaseEntity<string>`...

Comment: Ok ok, let me give it a turn, i think it can be feasible, but tricky.

Comment: Basically I think I should rather be passing some sort of `SecurityProviderFactory` to my `SecureSelf` method as I should be securing **all** properties of different type at the same time. My `SecureSelf` method should then be asking this factory for individual providers to convert particular properties. How would you implement it to secure integers and strings then? Any idea?

Comment: A fast question, why dont you just use IConvertible instead of ageneric method? With a constrain you ensure that TypeX can be casted to IConvertible, but any IConvertible is not ensured to allow to cast to TSecurable, that's the root of your problem

Comment: Right... but according to my additional info (see question or my previous comment here) I still won't be able to secure both integers and strings...

Comment: Thanks for the update but I must say that Lee's solution with generic method is better as I don't have to cast results to anything as `ISecurityProvider.Secure` method will return correct type. In your example it returns `IConvertible` that would require casting... and BTW, you likely don't require **explicit** parameter casting to `IConvertible`, do you, as both values are already `IConvertible`?

Comment: It does, remove the casts an you will get a complain about that must be converted.

Comment: I'm talking about parameter casting and not result casting. [Here's running code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/McI11X) that proves that parameters don't need to be cast to `IConvertible`.

Comment: Yup, you are right, had a previous error before on the Error list, editting the answer